# Error Favicon only in Chrome for Laravel API & VUE

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, google-chrome

I experience an unknown behaviour of my Laravel API (Backend) and VUE Frontend Website.

Chrome shows this Favicon:

[error favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxOoX.png)

This happens only in Google Chrome. There are no errors in Developer Tools & Console - There are no errors in Laravel Logs...

Everything seems to work fine. This happens only on a single Frontend Route...

Does somebody has an Idea what to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: add more info, like your index.html or package.json where you reference the favicon

Answer (score 0):

I think it has been solved... in fact a favicon.ico file in the directory "public" existed ... But the favicon was 0 byte (empty). I replaced it with a regular favicon - now everything is correct.